# Populating objects from cloud records (or another external source) using a generic function

Tags: swift, generics, core-data, protocols, swift-protocols

I'm building a generic API for my Swift applications. I use `CoreData` for local storage and `CloudKit` for cloud synchronization.

in order to be able to work with my data objects in generic functions I have organized them as follows (brief summary):

- Objects that go in the `CoreData` Database are `NSManagedObject` instances that conform to a protocol called `ManagedObjectProtocol`, which enables conversion to `DataObject` instances
- `NSManagedObject`s that need to be cloud synced conform to a protocol called `CloudObject` which allows populating objects from records and vice-versa
- Objects I use in the graphic layer of my apps are NSObject classes that conform to the `DataObject` protocol which allows for conversion to `NSManagedObject` instances

an object of a specific class. What I would like this code to look like is this:

```
for record in records {
    let context = self.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    //classForEntityName is a function in a custom extension that returns an NSManagedObject for the entityName provided. 
    //I assume here that recordType == entityName
    if let managed = self.persistentContainer.classForEntityName(record!.recordType) {
        if let cloud = managed as? CloudObject {   
            cloud.populateManagedObject(from: record!, in: context)
        }
    }
 }
```

However, this gives me several errors:

```
Protocol 'CloudObject' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
Member 'populateManagedObject' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'CloudObject'; use a generic constraint instead
```

The CloudObject protocol looks as follows:

```
protocol CloudObject {
    associatedtype CloudManagedObject: NSManagedObject, ManagedObjectProtocol

    var recordID: CKRecordID? { get }
    var recordType: String { get }

    func populateManagedObject(from record: CKRecord, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Promise<CloudManagedObject>
    func populateCKRecord() -> CKRecord
}
```

Somehow I need to find a way that allows me to get the specific class conforming to `CloudObject` based on the `recordType` I receive. How would I Best go about this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the CloudObject protocol?

Comment: thx, I posted it!

Comment: Do you need to return `Promise<CloudManagedObject>`? For example, it cannot be something like `Promise<NSManagedObject & ManagedObjectProtocol>` ? One way to achieve what you want is removing `associatedtype` from your `CloudObject`.

Answer (score 1):

As the data formats of CoreData and CloudKit are not related you need a way to efficiently identify CoreData objects from a CloudKit record and vice versa.

My suggestion is to use the same name for CloudKit record type and CoreData entity and to use a custom record name (string) with format `<Entity>.<identifer>`. `Entity` is the record type / class name and identifier is a CoreData attribute with **unique** values. For example if there are two entities named `Person` and `Event` the record name is `"Person.JohnDoe"` or `"Event.E71F87E3-E381-409E-9732-7E670D2DC11C"`. If there are CoreData relationships add more dot separated components to identify those

For convenience you could use a helper enum `Entity` to create the appropriate entity from a record

```
enum Entity : String {
    case person = "Person"
    case event = "Event"

    init?(record : CKRecord) {
        let components = record.recordID.recordName.components(separatedBy: ".")
        self.init(rawValue: components.first!)
    }
}
```

and an extension of `CKRecord` to create a record for specific record type from a `Entity` (in my example `CloudManager` is a singleton to manage the CloudKit stuff e.g. the zones)

```
extension CKRecord {
    convenience init(entity : Entity) {
        self.init(recordType: entity.rawValue, zoneID: CloudManager.shared.zoneID)
    }

    convenience init(entity : Entity, recordID : CKRecordID) {
        self.init(recordType: entity.rawValue, recordID: recordID)
    }
}
```

When you receive Cloud records extract the entity and the unique identifier. Then try to fetch the corresponding CoreData object. If the object exists update it, if not create a new one. On the other hand create a new record from a CoreData object with the unique record name. Your `CloudObject` protocol widely fits this pattern, the associated type is not needed (by the way deleting it gets rid of the error) but add a requirement `recordName`

```
var recordName : String { get set }
```

and an extension to get the `recordID` from the record name

```
extension CloudObject where Self : NSManagedObject {

    var recordID : CKRecordID {
        return CKRecordID(recordName: self.recordName, zoneID: CloudManager.shared.zoneID)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! The structure I currently have with DataObejcts, ManagedObjectProtocols and CloudObjects already allows me to identify what kind of object I need based on a recordType. The purpose of this question was to find out a way to actually populate those different kinds of objects using a generic function. Removing the associatedType in CloudObject fixed the error and thereby allowed me to do just that, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Swift is not Java, Swift is like C++, `associatedType` is a way of writing a generic `protocol`, and generics in Swift means C++ template.

In Java, `ArrayList<String>` is the same type as `ArrayList<Integer>`!!

In Swift (and C++) , `Array<String>` is ***NOT*** the same type as `Array<Int>`

So, you can't take an array of `Array`s for example,  you MUST make it an array of `Array<SpecificType>`

What did Apple do to make you able to make a "type-erased" array for example?

They made `Array<T>` extend `Array<Any>`.

If you want to immitate this in your code, how?

```
protocol CloudObject {
    // Omitted the associatedtype (like you already done as in the replies)
    //associatedtype CloudManagedObject: NSManagedObject, ManagedObjectProtocol

    var recordID: CKRecordID? { get }
    var recordType: String { get }

    func populateManagedObject(from record: CKRecord, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Promise<NSManagedObject & ManagedObjectProtocol>
    func populateCKRecord() -> CKRecord
}
```

Then make the "generic protocol", this would be useful in safely and performance programming when the resolving of protocol is known at compile time

```
protocol CloudObjectGeneric: CloudObject {
    // Generify it
    associatedtype CloudManagedObject: NSManagedObject, ManagedObjectProtocol

    // You don't need to redefine those, those are not changed in generic form
    //var recordID: CKRecordID? { get }
    //var recordType: String { get }
    //func populateCKRecord() -> CKRecord

    // You need a new function, which is the generic one
    func populateManagedObject(from record: CKRecord, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Promise<CloudObject>
}
```

Then make the generic protocol conform to the non-generic one, not to need writing 2 `populateManagedObject` functions in each implementation

```
extension CloudObjectGeneric {
    // Function like this if the generic was a parameter, would be
    // straightforward, just pass it with a cast to  indicate  you
    // are NOT CALLING THE SAME FUNCTION, you are calling it  from
    // the generic one,  but here the generic is in the return, so
    // you will need a cast in the result.
    func populateManagedObject(from record: CKRecord, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Promise<CloudObject> {

         let generic = populateManagedObject(from record: CKRecord, in context: NSManagedObjectContext)
         return generic as! Promise<CloudObject> // In Promises I think this
                       // will NOT work, and you need .map({$0 as! CloudObject})
    }
}
```